# Private Beta Site: Materials Modeling

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

If this is off-topic, I can take it down, but I think it's valuable to support other science sites in the network.

[Materials Modeling SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/) entered private beta at the end of April. The site aims to address research level questions about both the theory, methods, and implementation behind modeling systems ranging from molecules and proteins, to nanoparticles/sheets/tubes and polymers, to crystals and topological materials. Users come from a wide range of disciplines (chemistry, material science, computational science, drug design) and use a wide range of different modeling frameworks (molecular dynamics, electronic structure theory, Markov models/statistical mechanics, fluid dynamics, machine learning). While our sites have fairly different scopes, we have seen some cross pollination of questions and users that try to bridge the gap between the two: [OR/Materials Connection](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/136/in-which-paper-or-at-which-point-in-time-did-this-cross-pollination-between-th?r=SearchResults).

The site is coming up on the decision whether it can move to public beta and we would really appreciate your support. If any of the topics above interest you, or you think there is something in the realm of material simulation/computation that could be addressed well there, please consider joining the site and asking/answering/upvoting some questions. We think this site could have real value to the scientific community and it has already attracted a healthy amount of attention from experts across different fields, but we need the SE network clearly sees that value to ensure that the site is maintained. I think with both of our sites being fairly new, its especially important to support each other and establish a framework for collaboration.

For more discussion of the scope of the site: [Topics](https://materials.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-topics-can-i-ask-about-here), [Distinguishing Features](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29831/how-can-this-proposal-be-clearly-distinguished-from-chemistry-physics-computat/29832#29832)

Comment: The site has officially moved to Public Beta! Thank you all for your support!